# Embedding project folders(lua) into exe

Tags: c++, lua

I searching for a long time how to embed project files like folders (with lua scripts and images) into exe.

Basically i have some folders which are needed to run my game and i want to hide them somehow. Because now they are opened and can be easy edited by everyone.

I saw method in which folders have been changed to .dll file to protect them.

Using visual studio 2013.
I'll be very thankful for an answer.

Comment: Add them to via the resource file. If you want to retain the folder structure archive them in a zip file and include that in the resource file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PhysicsFS](http://icculus.org/physfs/), which allows to map a hierarchical filesystem to an archive. From the project page: "It is intended for use in video games, and the design was somewhat inspired by Quake 3's file subsystem." It's used by some open-source Lua frameworks (for example, [Love2d](http://love2d.org)), so you may check how they implemented the integration and access.

This doesn't guarantee full protection (nothing does), but it will at least make it more difficult for the users to make changes to those resources you want to protect.